# java runtime environment no result

Tags: java, python

I am trying to call python within my java code. However I found that if I import numpy in my python code, this is my java code

```
Process pcs = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
String result = null;
    

BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(pcs.getInputStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));        
System.out.println("\nExecuting python script file now.");
String lineStr = null;
    while ((lineStr = br.readLine()) != null) {
    result = lineStr;
}
br.close();
in.close();
System.out.println("done!");
System.out.println(result);
```

This is my python code:

```
import sys 
import os
import numpy as np

a = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]
print("hello world!")
print("%s * %s = %s"%(a,b,int(a)*int(b)))
```

Results if I don't include "import numpy as np":
10 * 11 = 110

Results if include "import numpy as np":
null

Any intuitive explanation?

Comment: OT: Just use Jython. Disclaimer: Please, never use Jython.

Comment: Please edit your question, it says the same for both results.

Comment: Would you be able to use the new ProcessBuilder API in Java, or do you have to use Runtime.exec?

Comment: I have already edited my question. I think I am just using Runtime,exec

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class Hello{
  public static void main(String[] args)throws java.io.IOException{
    Process pcs=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python test.py 8 5");// in linux or unix use python3 or python
    String result=null;
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(pcs.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));        
    System.out.println("\nExecuting python script file now.");
    String lineStr = null;
    while ((lineStr = br.readLine()) != null) {
      result = lineStr;
    }
    br.close();
    in.close();
    System.out.println("done!");
    System.out.println(result);
  }
 }
```

java code
compile:
javac Hello.java
run:
java Hello

```
#test.py
import sys 
import os
import numpy as np
a = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]
print("hello world!")
print("%s * %s = %s"%(a,b,int(a)*int(b)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the right PYTHONPATH setup in your application? When you have `import numpy as np` in your code, you may be receiving back empty STDOUT and an ModuleNotFoundError in STDERR. You can confirm by extracting STDERR - or check with this code:

```
Launch.exe(cmd);
```

where Launch.java is:

```
public class Launch
{
    /** Launch using FILE redirects */
    public static int exec(String[] cmd) throws InterruptedException, IOException
    {
        System.out.println("exec "+Arrays.toString(cmd));

        Path tmpdir = Path.of(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);

        Path out = tmpdir.resolve(cmd[0]+"-stdout.log");
        Path err = tmpdir.resolve(cmd[0]+"-stderr.log");
        pb.redirectError(out.toFile());
        pb.redirectOutput(err.toFile());

        Process p = pb.start();
        int rc = p.waitFor();

        System.out.println("Exit "+rc +' '+(rc == 0 ? "OK":"**** ERROR ****")
                          +" STDOUT \""+Files.readString(out)+'"'
                          +" STDERR \""+Files.readString(err)+'"');
        System.out.println();
        return rc;
    }
}
```

The fix for using numpy should be to access ProcessBuilder `pb.environment()` and set your PYTHONPATH for the subprocess before calling `start()`